# How to test iOS apps on iPhone with only OS X 10.10?

Tags: ios, xcode

Xcode 7 allows you to test and debug iOS apps on iPhone (similar to android)

However I am running os x yosemite 10.10 and it is impossible for me to upgrade my os.
According to the docs, I need at the very least 10.10.4 in order to obtain xcode 7.

I saw on stackoverflow that xcode 7 beta is available to 10.10. My question is I don't know if the beta supports physical iPhone testing?

So if I try xcode 7 beta, can I test on a physical device? Or can I somehow get physical iPhone testing on xcode6.4 (the latest version yosemite 10.10 allows me to have)? Thanks

Comment: Why can't you update from 10.10 to 10.10.5? It just a bug fix update.

Comment: @rmaddy It is a version of Niresh Hackintosh on Virtualbox, unfortunately I don't think there is a 10.10.5 version on there yet. If someone knows any different, please let me know!